# prevent add one existing project to all configuration in VS 2010 when add to one configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have  2 configuration except DEBUG/x64 and Release/x64 in VS2010 .I have selected 2 configuration for build on server named as TFSdebug/x64 and TFSRelease/x6 . I select some of project to build on server and checkin build results for all developers.but when I add an existing project to  one configuration for example debug ,vs2010 add it to all configurations and   causes to fail my build on server .how can i prevent from adding one project to all configurations when add to one configuration?